# How can I set self join in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
db={
  comments: [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5f364189f412c01fd01abab3"),
      "content": "Comment 1",
      "parent_comment_id": "",
      "date": 1592461538923
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5f364642f412c01fd01abeu4"),
      "content": "Replied",
      "parent_comment_id": "5f364189f412c01fd01abab3",
      "date": 1592461538926
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5f364642f412c01fd01abtx5"),
      "content": "fresh comment",
      "parent_comment_id": "",
      "date": 1592461538929
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve self join in mongodb based on parent_comment_id.

is it possible in mongodb as like mysql ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using aggregation [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/index.html),

- [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) for convert `parent_comment_id` to object if not empty, if its already an object id then skip this pipeline

```
db.comments.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      parent_comment_id: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $eq: ["$parent_comment_id", ""] },
          then: "$parent_comment_id",
          else: { $toObjectId: "$parent_comment_id" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

- [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) to join with self collection, and use lookup with pipeline to match condition
- [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) `parent_comment_id` to `_id`

```
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "comments",
      le": { pid: "$parent_comment_id" },
      as: "parentComment",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$pid", "$_id" ] }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to deconstruct `parentComment` because its an array and we need an object
- `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` to ignore empty `parentComment` array

```
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$parentComment",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c_xymap3CXa)